# Cannot display properly item metadata title in item page?

Tags: java, dspace

I have included a new `pagesNos` field as metadata in Dublin core. I was able to display it in the item display page. However one problem the page shows the name of Dublin core property as `metadata.dc.pages`. I want it to just show "Number of pages".

I don't have a Dspace source directory so I don't have a `message.properties` file. How do I change it directly in the `Dspace` installation directory?

Note: I am using dspace 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default messages.properties is embedded in dspace-api-lang-5.X.X.jar. If you have custom messages as Dspace documentation advise, maintained in additions module, custom messages are in additions-5.X.jar.
unzip it, edit and add again into the jar.

Comment: Where can I find message.properties in version 6? I would like to add some metadata in simple item record page. Would anyone show a working example in version 6? Thx

Comment: If yo are using Dspace 6.x, message files are at dspace-api-lang-6.x.x.jar. 
To show new metadata on item view you should chech display-item.jsp

Comment: And I don't have to change dpsace.cfg? There is a section dedicated to this issue, but it is commented in ####. Do I need to delete these characters? Thx.

Comment: And where can I edit this when I using **XMLUI** as the main interface? [link] (https://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/)